# ElasticSearch 6.0 timeout on cluster

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, timeout

I've 3 differents server with 1 instance of ES 6.0 on each and another server with nodejs, to query on.

On each server I just changed :

```
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts : [ LIST_ES_IP ]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
```

My problem is that after some times (not define), I've timeout error from nodejs server. But if I call

```
curl -XGET 'IP:9200/_cluster/health?pretty'
```

On this same server, I can see that ES works fine.

If I remove one server from cluster (comment previous 2 config lines), and query only on it, all works good & I never have timeout.

Did I need to change another config to make this cluster works ?
Did you have ideas about why I've timeout only on cluster mode ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's cause on **elasticsearch-js** client because I reactivate cluster, but define host to

```
"IP:9200"
```

and it works for 3 hours now.

Before I've

```
[ "IP1:9200", "IP2:9200", "IP3:9200" ]
```

I try with

```
[ {host: "IP", port: 9200}, {...} ]
```

But time out too..

So no way to have rollback if one server failed ?